# Reload Bootstrap Toast without reload the page (with django)

Tags: django, bootstrap-4, toast

**EDIT :**
I succeed to show the message but the data-delay is not respected, the toast does not disappear.

```
<div id="result" aria-live="polite" aria-atomic="true" style="position: relative">
        <div style="position: absolute; top: 12px; right: 12px;" >
            {% for message in messages %}
                    <div class="toast d-flex toast-success" role="alert" aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true" data-delay="3000">
                        <div class="toast-header toast-success shadow-none" >
                            <i class="fas fa-check"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div class="toast-body">
                            {{message}} 
                        </div>
                    </div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>
```

Original message :

I have a bootstrap toast (v 4.5.3)

```
<div class="toast d-flex toast-success" role="alert" aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true" data-delay="3000">
    <div class="toast-header toast-success">
         <i class="fas fa-check"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="toast-body">
         {{message}} 
    </div>
</div>
```

After submiting a form with Ajax POST I want to reload the Toast to show the new message generated in my django view. Can I do that without reloading the entire page ?

Comment: in success part add this script. $('#results').load(location.href + " #results>*", "") this will reload 'results' div. change <div class="toast-body" id="results">

Comment: @harshilsuthar thanks but it doesn't work. I succeed to show the message by putting the id in the first div but not the data-delay is not respected, the toast does not disapear